# Mongoose create a new object within a static function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

How do I create a new object within one of my static methods defined in the schema?

I basically have

```
UserSchema.statics.createUser = function (username, password, cb) { .. }
```

And I want to be able to save a new instance of the user object inside the function. I want to do something like `var user = new User(...)` within that method, but it of course doesn't work because the User model was not yet created.

What do I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you first call the static function **this** is bound to the model for the schema.  You can just do something like this:

```
someSchema.static('foo', function() {
    const newUser = new this({
        username: username, 
        password: password,
    });
    newUser.save(cb);
})
```

Don't replace the anonymous function with a fat arrow equivalent (I know you want to!). **this** won't have the correct scope.

Comment: I've tried that before and it didn't work. But I just realized I did it inside of a callback. Thanks!

Comment: i have tried but it sats "this is not a constructor".

Comment: For others googling this issue. @NisanthSojan When I had this error, it was because I was defining the function as () => {}, but you should use function() {}.

Comment: Tried that, but says `this is not a constructor`

Comment: @Mendes I fixed it by not using arrow functions, so `this` can be accessed. It's mentioned here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Answer (score 0):

Something that I believe should work is if you call the `mongoose.model` function so you're referencing `SomeSchema` without using `this`.

```
someSchema.static('foo', function() {
   return new mongoose.model("SomeSchema")({
       username: username, 
       password: password,
    })
})
```

I think that's how it would be. Also, I did `SomeSchema` because following regular naming conventions when you export the model it starts with capital so it's not referencing the actual schema but instead the model that will be created later. The way I did it in my project is

```
const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...},
   statics:{
    foo(){
      return new mongoose.model("SomeSchema")({username: username, password: password})
     }

   })

module.exports = mongoose.model("SomeSchema", someSchema)
```